# homebrew can't install taps 'Homebrew/homebrew-versions is not a valid repository name`

Tags: homebrew

I'm trying to install a specific version of the varnish tool via homebrew. Below is what I am attempting.

```
❯❯❯ brew search varnish
varnish
homebrew/php/php53-varnish                    homebrew/php/php54-varnish                    homebrew/php/php55-varnish                    homebrew/php/php56-varnish                    homebrew/versions/varnish3

❯❯❯ brew install homebrew/versions/varnish3
==> Tapping homebrew/versions
Cloning into '/usr/local/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-versions'...
fatal: remote error:
  /Homebrew/homebrew-versions is not a valid repository name
  Email support@github.com for help
Error: Failure while executing: git clone https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-versions /usr/local/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-versions --depth=1
```

I've updated to latest version via `brew update`, and have checked for issues via `brew doctor` to no avail.

Why am I being told it's not a valid repository name when it shows up in `brew search`?

The one thing I think could possible have done it is I added a setting to my global git configuration to convert all https references to ssh:

`url.ssh://git@github.com/.insteadof=https://github.com`

would this cause homebrew to break?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ahh -- seems I spoke too soon! I've figured out the issue.

So globally changing all https to ssh in git did in fact break homebrew. I went into `~/.gitconfig` and removed the https-to-ssh rewrite. Homebrew is now working as expected. Will leave this here incase anyone else comes across this particular issue.

Comment: I will as soon as I am able to -- says I must wait until tomorrow.